# Two Planets with different radii, same mass and same angular velocity orbit a star on a straight line.

Tags: classical-mechanics

I tried to solve the following exercise in theoretical mechanics: Two Planets A and B with equal mass $m$and equal angular velocity $w_0$(constant) move around the sun $S$ with mass $M$ in circular concentric orbits with radius $r_1$ for Planet A and radius $r_2$ for Planet B, but such that they are always on the straight line SAB. Find the angular velocity and the mass of the planets.

My idea:

If you look at Planet A: There is a gravitational force towards the sun but also a gravitational force towards B. The addition of both forces must be the centripetal (radial) force because the planet is moving on a circle, so we can write:

$mr_1w_0^2= \frac{GmM}{r_1^2}-\frac{Gm^2}{(r_2-r_1)^2} $

The minus can be explained by the direction of the forces: the gravitational force towards the Sun ans planet B are in opposite directions.

This can be also done for Planet B but here the gravitational force towards the sun and the planet A are in same direction, thus:

$mr_2w_0^2= \frac{GmM}{r_2^2}+\frac{Gm^2}{(r_2-r_1)^2} $

I can use both of the equations to determine $w_0$ and $m$ but are they even correct? Am I even on the right track?
I’d be very thankful if someone could take a look :)

Comment: Well! It's better to use your intuition than rigorous proof.

Comment: Have you asked in Physics Stack Exchange https://physics.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: The equations look OK, if $A$ is between $S$ and $B$. It might be possible to have the sun in the middle.

Comment: Nope, A is always between S and B.

Comment: Are the equations right then?

Comment: You've balanced the forces, so yes. But I'll echo David Quinn that your question is about the physics of the problem, not the mathematics. As such it would have been better asked on the physics forum than here.